# Me inicia sesión con cualquier email y contraseña - login php

Tags: php, login, session

Quiero saber por que me inicia la sesión con cualquier email o contraseña que ingrese. Pareciera que no pasa por mi base de datos para verificar los datos. Modificando el `$resultado == false` a  `$resultado !== false` me ocurre lo inverso, no me deja entrar con ningún email o contraseña, incluso habiendo ingresado el email y la contraseña que ya están registrados en la base de datos, mostrándome el error de `$errores .= 'Datos Incorrectos';`.

Cambie casi todo el código aun no consigo descubrir por que sucede esto. Soy nuevo en esto. Les agradecería la ayuda.

Acá les dejo el *PHP*:

```
<?php session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: contenido.php');
}
$errores = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sd_radio', 'root', '$"%"#%lf');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();;
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :usuario AND contraseña = :password'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':usuario' => $usuario, 
        ':password' => $password,
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if ($resultado == false) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: contenido.php');
    } else {
        $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
    }
}

require 'views/iniciar-sesion.php';
?>
```

Y acá el código *HTML* de `iniciar-sesion.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" class="form-login" method="POST" name="login">
            
                <?php 
                include_once 'login.php';
                if(!empty($errores)): ?>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <?php echo $errores; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                
                <input type="email" name="usuario" id="usuario">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                <button type="submit" onclick="login.submit()">Iniciar sesion</button>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En tu if $resultado == false, la variable resultado igual a false significa que no obtuvo resultados no?, entonces creo que tienes tu if alrevez

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin acabo de probar lo que me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Pues primero que nada, estás evaluado mal `$resultado`. Le dices que si el == falso, que entre... cosa que es SUPER erronea. Segundo. Evalúa tu mismo que valores obtienes del `$resultado`, haz un var_dump() justo despues de asignarlo e imprimelo. Luego analiza y evalua de modo diferente en el if.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Excorpion, debes imprimir la variable para ver que te llega

Comment: intetalo asi `if ( !empty($resultado['usuario'])){ //resto del codigo }` saludos.